# Optimize switch between child class of same parent class

Tags: c#, inheritance

Hello
I want to know if there is a best practice code for this example or tips for make more simple.
All classes are classes children of Choix but all methods are override in the child class.
If I tried with Choix Choix =new AddTenant but without success
Thank you for any further help/answer

```
string arguments = args[0].ToLower();
bool load;
bool lauch;
bool result;
switch (arguments)
{
case "AddTenant":
    AddTenant AddTenant = new AddTenant();
    load = AddTenant.Load();
    lauch = AddTenant.Lauch();
    result = AddTenant.Result();
    break;
case "BackupDb":
    BackupDb BackupDb = new BackupDb();
    load = BackupDb.Load();
    lauch = BackupDb.Lauch();
    result = BackupDb.Result();
    break;
case "ExtractTenant":
    ExtractTenant ExtractTenant = new ExtractTenant();
    load = ExtractTenant.Load();
    lauch = ExtractTenant.Lauch();
    result = ExtractTenant.Result();
    break;
case "InstallDb":
    InstallDb InstallDb = new InstallDb();
    load = InstallDb.Load();
    lauch = InstallDb.Lauch();
    result = InstallDb.Result();;
    break;
case "RestoreDb":
    RestoreDb RestoreDb = new RestoreDb();
    load = RestoreDb.Load();
    lauch = RestoreDb.Lauch();
    result = RestoreDb.Result();
    break;
case "UpgradeTenant":
    UpgradeTenant UpgradeTenant = new UpgradeTenant();
    load = UpgradeTenant.Load();
    lauch = UpgradeTenant.Lauch();
    result = UpgradeTenant.Result();
    break;
default:
    Help Help = new Help();
    load = Help.Load();
    lauch = Help.Lauch();
    result = Help.Result();
    break;
}
Console.WriteLine(load+" "+lauch+" "+result);
```

Comment: Do the various `ExtractTenant`, `InstallDb`, etc implement the same interface? Or can you make them implement the same interface with `Load`, `Lau(n)ch`, `Result` methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the classes are child classes of Choix and methods are properly overriden, what you propose should work:

```
string arguments = args[0].ToLower();

Choix choix;
switch (arguments)
{
    case "AddTenant":
        choix = new AddTenant();
        break;
    case "BackupDb":
        choix = new BackupDb();
        break;
    case "ExtractTenant":
        choix = new ExtractTenant();
        break;
    case "InstallDb":
        choix = new InstallDb();
        break;
    case "RestoreDb":
        choix = new RestoreDb();
        break;
    case "UpgradeTenant":
        choix = new UpgradeTenant();
        break;
    default:
        choix = new Help();
        break;
}

bool load = choix.Load();
bool lauch = choix.Lauch();
bool result = choix.Result();

Console.WriteLine(load + " " + lauch + " " + result);
```

This is an option of how your classes should be looking like:

```
abstract class Choix
{
    public abstract bool Load();
    public abstract bool Lauch();
    public abstract bool Result();
}

class AddTenant : Choix
{
    public override bool Load()
    {
        // Load ...
        return true;
    }

    public override bool Lauch()
    {
        // Lauch ...
        return true;
    }

    public override bool Result()
    {
        // Result ...
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't necessarily have to be abstract, but they have to be virtual methods at least, so you are able to override them.